# How do I get an old microscope adaptor to work when the K-3 is asking for F-stop data?

Tags: dslr, pentax, k-mount

I have fitted an old manual microscope objective mount to my Pentax K-3. It asks for the F-stop to proceed, which the lens cannot provide. I have tried all settings in the camera including manual focus and all options through the menu.

I imagine this problem is common to all older manual lenses.

Comment: Could it be that it's not asking for the f-stop (aperture) but for the focal length, in mm? That's only needed for SR (shake reduction), so either turn SR off or just enter any value.

Comment: Did you set "Using aperture ring" to "Enable"?

Comment: [Here's more](https://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/54-pentax-lens-articles/110657-how-use-meter-manual-m42-lenses-all-pentax-dslrs-k-1-k-3-k-5-k-30-etc.html). Does your adapter short the electrical contacts (it should according to that post).